# MATLAB newbie: error using sprintf. Function is not defined for 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder' inputs

Tags: matlab, printf, string-formatting

Today I tried to run a MATLAB m-file that someone gave me.  It works fine for him, but I encountered a warning and errors (below).  I am using a Mac with OS X Yosemite (10.10.5) and a new version of MATLAB (R2015b).  The person who prepared the m-file would have used an older one and Windows.

From a blog at Mathworks and posts online/here, the error seems to be due to a MATLAB update--a change from using numeric values to point towards graphics objects to using objects themselves. I understand this in theory, but don't know how to fix my code (it has been years since I used MATLAB regularly, so I'm pretty lost).

> Warning: Text handle output is not supported when a contour handle
>   argument is supplied and label placement is automatic.
>
> > In clabel (line 214)
> >     In control_volume_20150706>plot_xxx (line 733)
> >     In control_volume_20150706 (line 104)
> >     In run (line 96)
>
> Error using sprintf 
>   Function is not defined for
>   'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder' inputs.
>
> Error in control_volume_20150706>plot_xxx (line 734)
>   sprintf('%10.4f \n',text_handle);
>
> Error in control_volume_20150706 (line 104) plot_xxx (nr,
>   xwidevec, yhighvec, omegamat, psimat, umat, vmat, ...
>
> Error in run (line 96) evalin('caller', [script ';']);

This is what the code looks like in the vicinity of line 733:

> Line 731 contourlevels = omegamat(1, :) ;
>   Line 732 [C,h] = contour(X,
>   Y, flipud(omegamat), contourlevels, 'LineWidth', 2 );
>   Line 733
>   text_handle = clabel(C,h);
>   Line 734 sprintf('%10.4f \n',text_handle);

I would be very grateful for any hints about how to deal with this.

Comment: See: [Graphics Handles Are Now Objects, Not Doubles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html). What is the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, excaza.  It should be a labeled plot.  I hope that's enough detail for you; I'm slowly going through the code and trying to understand it (very rusty with MATLAB). Thanks also for the link.  That's the one I found, but I'm having troubling figuring out what to do to my code in practice.

Comment: sprintf is for printing strings. I don't understand why it's even present in the code, its output is suppressed and it is not saved to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll try commenting it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `h` is a handle which refers to some object, then in R2015a and later this is the object itself, while in previous versions it's a double which points to an object (as you noted in the question). You can use `h.double` in R2015a and later to get what would previously be `h`. E.g., pre-R2015a `h = figure(999)` would set `h` to `999`, a double; with R2015a and later `h` is an object and `h.double` is `999`.

Comment: In your example this means you should change Line 734 to `sprintf('%10.4f \n',text_handle.double);`

Comment: Thank you very much!  I didn't realize how similar MATLAB is to C++.  I'm not sure if the sprintf('%10.4f \n',text_handle.double) command even does anything, but I hate to have errors.

Comment: well, since it has a semicolon at the end it doesn't do anything at all. But if you were to remove the semicolon `sprintf` would print a string to the command window with the doubles which would point to the graphics object in previous versions of MATLAB. Not really sure how this is useful in R2015a. But it's worth reading more about `sprintf` and `fprintf`. Syntax is very similar to `fprintf` in `C` if you are familiar with that.